# Azure DevOps pipeline takes long time for copying node modules

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

Have been setting up an Azure DevOps pipeline for bundling a function and deploying it over to GCP (deplyoment part is working fine and no issues).

But the overall process takes a lot of time, is there any suggestion how can we reduce the time of deployment?

azure-pipeline.yaml

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/functions'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

While release pipeline is just reading the drop and pushing it via shell script.

[image]

The overall pipeline takes a lot of time in copying the nodefile after npm install to the drop (over 10 minutes). Is there any way make this process fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your YAML file, you have included all files  when copy and publish to drop folder.

The alternative is choosing necessary files and excluding `node_modules` folder from publishing to server. This will help to reduce time. A sample UI setting for reference.:

#### Copy Files task

Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

Contents:

```
**\**
!**\node_modules\**
```

Target Folder: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

[image]

#### Publish Build Artifacts task

Publish Build Artifacts task: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

Artifact Name: `drop`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PatricLu-MSFT but copying all files in mandatory in this case, as function deployment need all those files. Will zipping the whole directory help? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @KumarVivek Kindly use both task https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops to archive and extract files.

Comment: Hi Kumar Vivek, any update on this? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested, were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi Patrick, tried to use the compress but unable to extract locate the files in release. Still struggling with it.

Comment: You should compress files in build pipeline first and then copy zipped files/folders to build .artifactstagingdirectory . And then publish `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` to drop folder. Finally select artifacts in release side from drop folder and unzip it in release pipeline. Hope it helps.